# Two divs stretched to the end of the page

Tags: web, height, scrollbar, css

I have an *OUTER* div with two inner divs:

- one of them is *VERTICAL SIDEBAR* whose content is fairly short
- second one is div with *MAIN PAGE* whose content varies

They are both set to float: left, so they are next to each other.

I already learned that when setting height or min-height in percentage, all the parents need to have their height specified also.

**I would like them both to be stretched to the end of the page.** Havent managed to do that, problems begin when *MAIN PAGE* div is longer than monitor height( so there needs to be scrollbar), then I usually end with that nasty scrollbar inside *MAIN PAGE* div or I end with the *SIDEBAR* div being too short.

Comment: show your "faulty" CSS and HTML code, also if you could explain a little better would be nice-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your site, this is the fix:

```
.Page {
width: 970px;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: table;
}
.Sidebar {
width: 257px;
background: url(img/sidebar-bg.png) repeat-y;
margin-left: 23px;
background: white;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: top;
}
.Sidebar-Nav {
padding-left: 15px;
}
.Content {
background: url(img/content-bg.png) repeat;
margin-left: 10px;
width: 680px;
float: left;
background: white;
display: table-cell;
padding: 10px;
}
```

EDIT: I forgot the .Page styles, I added it.

EDIT: Also, if you want to center it, then use this:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
body {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
line-height: 21px;
background: url(img/bg-page-01.jpg) no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 0%;
}
.Page {
height: 100%;
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.Sidebar {
width: 257px;
height: 100%;
background: url(img/sidebar-bg.png) repeat-y;
background: white;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: top;
}
.Sidebar-Nav {
padding-left: 15px;
}
.Content {
height: 100%;
background: url(img/content-bg.png) repeat;
margin-left: 10px;
width: 680px;
float: left;
background: white;
display: table-cell;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok you should set the Outer divs css like so

```
.outer{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

This will set the outer div to completely fill the window, with a side bar to scroll the length of the rest of the page. You would only have one main side scrollbar.

Now if you want the sidebar to just fill the page. set its css like so:

```
 .sideBar{
      position:absolute //can be relative if necesary.
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      overflow:none;
 }
```

Now this sets the sidebar to the exact height of the outer div. so it will span the entire page and the overflow is set to none to ensure no scrollbar.

Now the outer div's and sidebar div's height should be dictated by the main div, and you should only have one clean scroll bar.

Comment: Interesting approach, but how should I set my inner divs? Remember that they have different content and they both need to be same lenght. Should I set them to 100%, either min-height or height?

Comment: ahh if you are setting the top and bottom attributes the height is not necesary, also if the right and left attributes are set width is not necesary. The main div's height will ultimately be the height of the page, using this method. Which can be anything really.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9z9aL/3/)

Setting `display: table-cell` on both `div`'s inside the outer `div` with `display: table-row` will ensure they are always the same height, you'll have to set `display: table` on `body` for this to work, or you could just set it directly on the outer `div` instead of `table-row`. That will work just fine. This approach should [work on anything better than IE7](http://caniuse.com/css-table).

**CSS:**

```
html {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: scroll-x;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: table;
}
.outer {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.sidebar, .mainpage {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div class="mainpage">mainpage</div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this solution, the sidebar is still short and not reaching end of the page

Comment: I realised my solution worked fine in Chrome and Firefox but still had some height issues in IE. I have edited the answer with a fix for those issues. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9z9aL/3/).

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about height issues here, then use this:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
min-height: 100% /* for firefox */
}
#main, #sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* eliminates increased height due to padding & child margins */
}
#sidebar { background: blue; width: 200px; float:left; margin: 0; }
#main { background: green; width: 960px; margin: 0 0 0 200px; }
```

edit: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jTwqe/

Comment: Not working either, the divs are not reaching end of the page when the page is longer than monitor

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your issue is, but is an alternate solution.

```
.outer { display: table; }
.sidebar, .main { display: table-cell; padding: 10px; }
.sidebar { background: green; }
.main { background: blue; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5CmR/

Comment: After seeing your comment in the other answer, and seeing the site, I think this one should solve your problem, but you will need to remove your float:left from your sidebar and add vertical-align: top.

Comment: Working! Is it now possible to possition the OUTER div in the middle? Margin 0 auto and setting fixed width for it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: Yes, read the other answer I gave. I did the code for you. Just copy & paste.